# What's a good strategy for using assert in Promise handlers

Tags: node.js, testing, promise, mocha.js

I'd like to test the values returned by an async operation using mocha. The values are provided via a plain A+ promise. Unfortunately the `.then` handler will now swallow all the exceptions thrown by `assert` so the tests will pass no matter what:

```
someOp().then(function(result){
  // throws, but will be swallowed
  assert(result.indexOf('I_DONT_WANT_THAT') < 0);
  done();
});
```

How can I correctly test the result of my async operation? All I can think of is endlessly propagating the error, but at some point I will need assert to throw a real error for my test to fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mocha can deal with promises if you return them:

```
it('value should be 0', function() {
  return Promise.resolve(1).then(function(value) {
    assert(value === 0);
  });
});
```